# Android Final vs Private textviews

Tags: java, android, final

simple maybe stupid question. I have a login activity which launches another activity, and here's the code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    final TextView tvUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
    final TextView tvPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPassword);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tvUsername.getText().toString().length()<1) {
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Enter a Username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 70);
                msg.show();
                tvUsername.requestFocus();
            } else if (tvPassword.getText().toString().length()<1) {
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Enter a Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 200);
                msg.show();
                tvPassword.requestFocus();
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,CrewScheduleActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

My question is about the textviews. Eclipse basically said i had to make them final in order to use them in the onClick event of the button. NP so i did that and it worked.

The question is What is the difference between putting these above the @Override as private vs inside the OnCreate as final?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with [closure in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29#Local_classes_.28Java.29). Basically, when you use an anonymous class, the values (not objects themselves) used within it are copied to that class for usage. Therefore, it does not make sense to return or modify those variables within the class, hence they must be `final`.

However, if the variable is instead part of the class *containing* the anonymous class, that's different. Basically, your inner class has a reference to the `LoginActivity` object (as `LoginActivity.this`), and can use and modify its members and methods.

When you put them "above the @Override", you are making them member variables of the `LoginActivity` class. Therefore, they can be accessed by the anonymous class.

Succinctly, the difference is that: `final` variables are local to the method, and copied to the anonymous class; member variables are local to the containing class and are modified by the anonymous class.

If you want to reuse the data from the anonymous class later, use a member variable. If you only need it within `onCreate()` and the anonymous class, then a `final` variable will suffice.

Comment: To add a little something, final fields declared in the enclosing block are guaranteed to be fully constructed and visible to other threads.

Comment: Ok, one more thing that's a little bit confusing. I just want to see if i'm understanding this correctly.   1. LoginActivity inherits from the Activity class because of the extends keyword.   2. The public Void OnCreate overrides the onCreate method of the Activity Class.  3. The Public void OnClick overrides? I'm kinda confused why override is there because im thinking like VBA here, onClick doesn't need to override anything lol

Comment: It implements an `OnClickListener`. If you take a look at the `OnClickListener` class, you will notice there is an `onClick` method there; you are overriding that, even though it is not an explicitly declared `implements` class. And yes, your other points are correct.

Comment: Oh, damn i didn't realize the OnClickListener is a class, ahh, lot's of reading to do. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

When you declare the TextView field (or any field for that matter) as public, it can be accessed directly by any other class, which I don't believe is your intention; there's no reason to make the TextView variable public. 
If it is set as private, there is a guarantee that its value won't be overridden in another class, which is what the **final** keyword was designed to do in the first place. So, simply set it as private, and you won't have to worry about Eclipse correcting you.

 
So, in summary: making the field private/final ensures that the value cannot be overridden from another class, which is a good design. 
 
Hope this rambling helps. I'll be glad to clarify it better if it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, i understand now. I completely didn't realize that public void onClick(View v) was an anonymous class within another class hehe. I think i'm going to keep them final for now. The next step is to use the values for login into a WCF web service, if i need them as private i will do that.

Comment: No problem; we are glad to help; if the answer helps, consider upvoting it too. Thanks.

Comment: the public void onClick(View w) is **not** an anonymous class; it's an overridden method within an anonymous class.

Comment: thanks, i guess it says requires 15 reputation, gonna have to figure out this rep thing

Comment: Come on here more often to help answer other people's questions too; it'll really help your reputation, as well as your knowledge. Check out http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java when you can.

Comment: Sorry, I had to downvote this. for the reasons that Eric has given in his answer. You have confused a lot of things here and you're description and confusion of variable scope, closure and private vs final are flat wrong.